# can emeditor's marco select multi-line simulatensly?

Tags: emeditor

i justi study and test emeditor's marco now
here i have a question about how can i use emediotr's marco to select multiline
for example
i want to select line-10 to line-20 simulatensly
how i can do it in marco language

i have know i can use this

```
document.selection.SetActivePoint(eePosView,1,10)
document.selection.selectline();
document.selection.SetActivePoint(eePosView,1,10)
document.selection.selectline();
```

but it can only select line-10 then line-20, there are two line
how can it select line-10 to line-20 simulatensly ,  like line-10 to line-20 , ther are 10 lines

my english is poor
thanks for you time to read my poor english
i don't have a skill for javascript , if possible, code as simple as stupid ,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select lines 10-20, You can write a macro like this:

```
document.selection.SetActivePoint(eePosView,1,10);
document.selection.SetActivePoint(eePosView,1,20,true);
```